# React: best practice for state control

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

Lately I've noticed that I'm writing a lot of React code were I have 2 components:

1. Data filter
2. Data display

In the first component I might have N possible filters to apply to the data. These filters often complex components on their own. When the user defines the filters I need to pass it from 1st component to the 2nd for display.
Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sutherland-16zhp8?file=/src/App.js

What I see in many cases to happen is that I manage the state of the filter in multiple places.
In the example above, I have it in the Toolbar component and in the parent one.

What is the best way of managing states in such case?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely never duplicate the state in multiple places as this can create bugs where they get out of sync. The solution is to hoist state and then pass it down via props, see https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components.

Here is your codesandbox modified as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wilbur-0xyi8f

Comment: But what if the toolbar has multiple different filters: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-euler-ybbejw?file=/src/App.js I need to pass the value and the onChange handler for each of them.

Comment: Thats correct and totally normal in react. It is desirable -- you need the state to be higher and pass the callbacks and data down. Duplicating state to avoid this is not a good idea and a bug in your application. If this get unwieldy youd start to consider a form lib like https://react-hook-form.com/ which has all the values in a larger store that can be accessed over context.

Comment: Is it overkill to use context for this? I can create a context that has the values and the setters in it. This way I don't need to pass anything.

Comment: If your use case is this simple -- yes its overkill. Prop drilling is fine here. As your app gets bigger though, you may want to reconsider; or if you know beyond doubt this state is going to grow and needs to be accessed in more places in future. Otherwise you fall into the classic "optimizing too early" trap which leads to unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You are duplicating the sate multiple times, plus there are some unnecessary helper functions along the way.

The state can be held in one place, with its setter function passed to the `toolbar` component, like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Tony Starks Nicknames</h1>
      <Toolbar searchStr={searchStr} onSearchStrChange={setSearchStr} />
      <List searchStr={searchStr} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, the toolbar can look like this:

```
function Toolbar({ searchStr, onSearchStrChange }) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    onSearchStrChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={searchStr}
        placeholder="search..."
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, there's only one place where the state is stored

Answer (score 0):

If your hierarchy's depth is or might become greater than 2, I would suggest the Context API.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html